# Как на странице детальной новости поставить компонент список новостей?

Tags: битрикс

Как на странице детальной новости поставить компонент список новостей?

Comment: Прочитав документацию. А затем добавив вызов нужного компонента в код шаблона детальной страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1: В комплексном компоненте `bitrix:news`, то в его шаблоне в файле `detail.php` после вызова компонента `bitrix:news.detail` добавьте вызов компонента `bitrix:news.list`.

Вариант 2: В шаблоне детального компонента `bitrix:news.detail` в нужном месте добавьте вызов компонента `bitrix:news.list`.

Для того, чтобы новый компонент добавился и его параметры можно было настроить в публичной части используйте такой код:

```
<?php $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
   "bitrix:news.list",
   ""
?>
```

Компонент добавиться на страницу с шаблоном по умолччанию, а вы в режиме правки сможете настроить его параметры как вам нужно.